# Set max-width of Vaadin Grid column

Tags: vaadin

Is it possible to set a max-width of a Vaadin Grid column?
In the Vaadin docs I only found how to set a fixed column width e.g. `.setWidth("7em").setFlexGrow(0)`  [Vaadin Grid documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/grid#column-width)

Is there something like `.setMaxWidth()` in the Grid API?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

I tried

```
Grid.Column.getElement().getStyle().set("max-width", "100px");
```

But that does not work either.